# What does shopt -s dirspell do?

Tags: bash, shopt

I cannot figure it out, i understand shopt -s cdspell but cannot find out what shopt -s dirspell does.

The Bash Reference Guide says:

dirspell

If set, Bash attempts spelling correction on directory names during word completion if the directory name initially supplied does not exist.

I tried several times on several directories but that is not the behavior.

I'm using bash 4.2.10(2) on i386-apple-darwin10.7.0

Answer (score 10):

From the [change-log](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES)

> x.  There is a new shell option: `dirspell'.  When enabled, the filename
>       completion code performs spelling correction on directory names during
>       completion.

Let's try:

```
$ ls
spam/

$ cat spam/test 
hello world
```

without `dirspell`

```
$ cat span/test [tab]
# nothing happens
```

with dirspell

```
$ shopt -s dirspell
$ cat span/test [tab]
#line is replaced by
$ cat /home/user/tmp/shopt/spam/test
```

Comment: Props for hinting that dirspell works from the second level of files/dirs, what actually makes sense, but when i tabcomplete, the second level file or dir gets completed with a space afterwards, and the result is a No such file or directory, which makes this shopt basicaly unpractical,useless, sensles for me? @Frederik

Comment: Yeah, I also do not get the line replacement.  Rather, the tab-completion works, but then the typo gets sent to the command so the command itself fails.

Comment: I don't see anything happening when I hit tab, with `dirspell` on.

Answer (score 7):

If you set the shell options *direxpand* and *dirspell*, then the tab-completion does work.

Comment: `direxpand` is available since [4.3-alpha](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#direxpand).